# Collapse "docs" for textmining in R

Tags: r

I've got a problem trying to us the FindAssocs code when converting a file from PDF using the  pdf_text code from the PDF Tools pacakge.

I've sort of pinpointed the issue. It's that because I can't use "readLines" the Corpus creates a separate area for each page in the PDF. So when I get to the FindAssocs, it returns 1's because they are on both pages.

Is there a workaround? For reference: code down below.

Thanks in advance :).

```
text <- pdf_text(file.choose())
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
inspect(docs)

toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", 
x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("dutch"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 10)

as.data.frame(findAssocs(dtm, terms = input$v, corlimit = 0.3))
```

Comment: Where does `input$v` come from?

Comment: @phiver it's a bit of tryout code, I'm writing a shiny. usually it should just state "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine all the pages you loaded with `pdf_text` into one field, you can use `paste(unlist(text), collapse =" ")` before you transform the text into a corpus.

```
# my test pdf consists of 20 pages.
text <- pdf_text(file.choose())
summary(text)
Length     Class      Mode 
   20 character character

# collapse the text into one field
text <- paste(unlist(text), collapse ="")
summary(text)
Length     Class      Mode 
    1 character character
```

Comment: Hey, 
I tried it out, which gave me a very weird result:
The "head"still is the same which is great, however.
    My findAssocs returns:
    > findAssocs(dtm, terms = "security", corlimit = 0.3)
    $security
    numeric(0)

Sorry i cant seem to turn the above answer in code form..

Comment: findAssocs finds correlations of the term between documents. If you only have 1 document, it will return 0. In your original code it would return the correlation of 'security' between the pages in the pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I've noticed that when I use the txt method I get a correlation of that one document though, or am I wrong?